# How to generate graph towers dynamically?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, dynamic, controller, thymeleaf

I am facing some problems to draw graph towers dynamically
Hello! I am sending data from **controller** to **Thymeleaf** Page and calling data using javascript.
Now, How can I generate the towers of graphs dynamically. Like we should have towers in numbers, that we have the number of products.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39430696/7482033 this may help . Try it out first

Comment: Thank you problem is solved

Comment: That's good to know so did the link works for you?

Comment: I did before I mean before your link.